# ubuntu 16.10 to 17.10 upgrade - don't get any menu in GUI

Tags: boot

by following below steps upgraded Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.10

7
down vote
First I would like to add that this is a hack, and problems may or may not arrise from doing this. I only tried this with Ubuntu Server 16.10.
I managed to upgrade from server release 16.10 to 17.10 by doing the following:
Open /etc/apt/sources.list :
vim /etc/apt/sources.list
Change all references from yakkety to artful:
:%s/yakkety/artful/g
Do an update and upgrade:
apt update && apt upgrade
Reboot the system.

[How to update Ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997047/how-to-update-ubuntu-from-16-10-to-17-10)

but after reboot it asks for user login and password but after that no menu options are visible. can't do anything. any help will be appreciated to fix the problem and get the GUI back.

I can't get access to terminal. How do I troubleshoot? It looks like upgrade is not successful but don't know how to investigate it.

regards

swanand

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I also followed the link that you posted on how to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.10 and I managed to fix this by running the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo init 6
```

You can also check [this link](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/).