# Ubuntu 16.10 Yakketty won't update. Can I fix it, or should I get 16.04, or 17.10?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, release-management

So I had a beautiful system running real nice up until I wanted to set up an old webcam last night. I did sudo apt-get update and got this:

```
Fetched 1,475 B in 3min 25s (7 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_16.10  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 12C6ADA61C85BB5E
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_16.10  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
```

And sudo apt-get install for anything yields

```
E: Package 'program' has no installation candidate
```

I suspect that I'm having this issue because I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. If not, I'd like to know how to fix it, because I really like my system the way it is. Otherwise, I'd consider installing 16.04 or 17.10, but I'd also like to know  which one is better, and if there is a way to install without losing all my programs and stuff. Some of them were pretty frustrating to install, and I really need them.

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is highly preferable to 17.10. Then I would wait until summer, fall or winter of 2018 to install 18.04 LTS if not longer.

Answer (score 5):

your problem is, as @Organic Marble said, that yakkety (16.10) is an "end-of-life" release.
For your problem to be fixed, you need to upgrade to another "end-of-life" release, which is zesty (17.04). And then, you have to upgrade from the latter to artful (17.10).

My answer is inspired by that [reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996768/upgrade-from-yakkety-yak-ubuntu-16-10-when-its-end-of-life).
In which, @kap gives us the way to do, in a quick way, due to the fact that his question has been marked as duplicate. There, I also want to thank @Sidepipe - read his answer and comment -.

I tested it twice in a virtual machine - with virtualbox -, and it worked.
I, then, applied it with my main machine, and it has also been successful.
I have to say that, this way out won't fix your "broken ppa". You'll have to find the right ppa for the artful release.

I won't explain everything. I'm sure you'll find answers by yourself, on [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) or elsewhere on the web.

Everything has to be done as root or via sudo.
To check your release:`$ lsb_release -a` or `$ cat /etc/os-release`

There we go, we have to parts.

## I) Upgrade from "end-of-life" yakkety (16.10) to "end-of-life" zesty (17.04)

1. Fix /etc/apt/sources.list.d

   - `# update-manager` - uncheck every ppa
2. Download [zesty.tar.gz](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/)
3. Verify package authenticity - gpg files at same url
4. Extract archive - and modify the following files

   - `# vi ./DistUgradeController.py"`

     - Change every "archive.ubuntu.com" ==> "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
     - Change every "security.ubuntu.com" ==> "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
   - `# vi ./mirrors.cfg`

     - Append "ubuntu/" to every "old-releases.ubuntu.com/"
5. /etc/apt/sources.list

   - Change every "fr.archive.ubuntu.com" ==> "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
   - Change every "security.ubuntu.com" ==> "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
6. `# apt-get update`
7. `# apt-get upgrade`
8. `# apt-get dist-upgrade`
9. `# ./zesty --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText`
10. `# reboot`
11. `# apt-get update` - troubles, see next step -
12. Delete duplicate(s) in /etc/apt/sources.list
13. `# apt-get update`
14. `# apt-get upgrade`
15. `# apt-get dist-upgrade`
16. `# apt-get autoremove`
17. `# apt-get autoclean`
18. `# reboot`

## II) Upgrade from "end-of-life" zesty (17.04) to artful (17.10)

1. `# do-release-upgrade`
2. `# reboot`
3. `# apt-get update`
4. `# apt-get upgrade`
5. `# apt-get dist-upgrade`
6. `# apt-get autoremove`
7. `# apt-get autoclean`
8. `# reboot`

Comment: Have to say - similar problem (lazy to perform update...), these instructions worked flawlessly for me on Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.10, thru 17.04 as described.

I wouldn't worry too much about system settings (OP) - as far as I can tell, it doesn't seem a whole lot has been broken by the process.

It will take time though - about 30 means each migration, so a solid hour. There are a few y/n question in between so you do need to pay a bit of attention.

Answer (score 3):

Your suspicion is correct! 16.10 went end-of-life last summer and is no longer supported.

You may still be able to upgrade to 17.10 (17.04 is also end-of-life), but I am not sure about that. The upgrade path(s) do not work forever.

18.04 comes out in a couple of months, and will be a Long Term Support release.

Reference: https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life